# How to use combobox.selected text in where clause of a query to get the value in same row but different column in database (C#)

Tags: c#

[in this image i tried to save the value in "cur" but it giving error cannot convert string to int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n7fY.png)i have a database table (tablename = currencyconverter) with two columns. "currencyname" and "currencyvalue".
i have a combobox and wants to run this query. select currencyvalue from currencyconverter where currencyname =" + comboBox2.SelectedText;
so the thing i want is when a text in combobox is selected the query should get the value and should save it in a variable.[this is the database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8zrV.png)

Comment: Ok, and where are you stuck?  There are many examples and tutorials available for using a database in C#.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: i updated the question. please refer to the image

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image. Instead use the code formatting block and paste your code here.

Answer (score 0):

> but it giving error cannot convert string to int

You're trying to reference a value by its column name:

```
mdr.GetInt32("currencyvalue")
```

However, [the `GetInt32()` method expects an integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) argument, not a string argument.  That integer would be the zero-based column ordinal.  Something like this:

```
mdr.GetInt32(0)
```

Comment: so how can i refer it to a column?

Comment: @AhmedRaza: If you really need to use the column name then you can use that to get the ordinal, and then use that ordinal to get the value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal.aspx  So something like: `mdr.GetInt32(mdr.GetOrdinal("currencyvalue"))`

Comment: @David there are so many errors in that piece of code that we are only scratching the surface here.

Comment: i have found a way. please tell me how can i save the value from the query to a variable?

Comment: @AhmedRaza: Is it not doing that already?  What specifically is the problem you're experiencing?  Include the actual code (not just pictures or links to pictures) in the question, and provide the exact error you're seeing.  If it's a new problem, it's also possibly worth opening a new question so that each one is separate and distinct.

Comment: if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter selectquery = new SqlDataAdapter ("select currencyvalue from currencyconverter where currencyname = '"+ comboBox2.SelectedText+"'",connection);
                cur =  "HERE I WANT THAT QUERY DERIVED VALUE TO BE SAVED"
                num = double.Parse(textBox6.Text);
                ans = cur * num;
                textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(ans);
            }
        }